# Ext.tree.Panel, itemclick, getTreeStore() not found in 5.x but works in 4.x

Tags: extjs, listeners, extjs5

this code works ok in 4.x. The goal is to open/close tree items with single click.
In 5.x after click occurs error: "self.getTreeStore is not a function"
I can't find the relevant change in API docs.
Could you give me a hint why 4.x and 5.x work different?

```
Ext.onReady(function(){
    Ext.create('Ext.tree.Panel', {
        border: false,
        height: 200,
        listeners: { itemclick: function(self, record, item, index, event) {
                       if (record.data.href=='') {
                         var Enode=self.getTreeStore().getNodeById(record.internalId);
                         if (Enode.isExpanded()) 
                           Enode.collapse();
                         else
                           Enode.expand();
                       } } },
        rootVisible: false,
        width: 200,
        root: {
            children: [ { 
               text: 'Menu 1',
               children: [{ text: 'Menu 1.1',leaf: true }]
            } ] },
        renderTo: Ext.getBody()
    });
});
```

regards,
annie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In 5.0 you can call just `tree.getStore()` or `tree.getRootNode().getTreeStore()` where `tree` is instance of `Ext.tree.Panel`.

But you don't need to do that in your case, because `record` in `itemclick` handler has all methods from `NodeInterface`. Try this instead:

```
itemclick: function(self, node, item, index, event) {
    if (node.data.href=='') {
        if (node.isExpanded()) {
            node.collapse();
        } else {
            node.expand();
        }
    } 
}
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/9KJME/1/

Answer (score 1):

@Lolo has described the solution. As to why it works differently - the `self` parameter is a `Ext.tree.View`, not an `Ext.tree.Panel`. It has different methods.

`Ext.tree.View` does have a `getStore()` method, but not a `getRootNode()`